# Change SCNReferenceNode width and height ratio

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, scnnode, arscnview

Hey Everyone)) I am new at `ARKit` and I have one problem.

I can't change programmatically `SCNReferenceNode` width and height ratio. [I tried to change **sacle x and y** in ".scn" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSVuP.png) and it is working.

But when I change it in code, it is not working.

```
    object.scale.x = 1
    object.scale.y = 2
```